# Adding CSS ease-in and ease-out transition for changing images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a simple ease-in and ease-out effect when you hover over a logo. I know there are posts about this. I've tried many different combinations of CSS, but can't seem to get it to work.

I've successfully changed the logo color by changing the content upon hover with this CSS code:

```
#dealertrackr-image.et_pb_image:hover {
content: url('image url');
}
```

When it is hovered over, the logo changes from the black and white state to colored state. I now want this to have a 1s ease-in and ease-out on hover and release of hover. Nothing that I tried worked.

http://www.nationalgalactic.com/divisions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you were hoping for was grayscale, you may also be interested in just loading in the full color image and using a CSS filter to desaturate / resaturate on hover.

This combined with CSS transitions will create a nice little fade:

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray; filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}
```

*edit 
This is a pure CSS solution, but is not fully supported in Android Jellybean, and Internet Explorer. If full browser support is important to you, please see isherwood's answer on this same post. For full support, your solutions are limited to stacked images or javascript.

Comment: Not bad, except for IE and Jelly Bean Android. http://caniuse.com/#search=grayscale

Comment: Great point. If full support is important (it always is), isherwood has the correct answer up above involving stacked fading images. The only disadvantage is the double requests for each image.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it with images is to stack elements and transition the opacity of the top layer. Browsers don't do image-to-image transitions.

Something like this, where the anchor has a background image:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/150/nature) left top no-repeat;
}
a img {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
a:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/150/nature/2" alt="">
</a>
```

**[Here's a demo](http://liveweave.com/66MxcH)** with your code and images.

Comment: I like that approach, so simple